# What is the significance of γενόμενοι in Luke 1:2?

Tags: greek, luke, grammar

What is the significance of γενόμενοι in Luke 1:2?  The translations seem to ignore it and translate Luke 1:2 the same as if it weren't there.  I haven't found a source that references this question.  It seems that it should be translated "exactly as those who from the beginning **became** eyewitnesses and servants of the word handed down to us." Or, "exactly as those who from the beginning **were** eyewitnesses and servants of the word handed down to us."

Comment: That's how it's translated : were, being eyewitnesses

Comment: _who from the beginning **became** eye-witnesses, and officers of the Word, -_ Young's Literal.

Comment: I stayed up too late when I looked at this verse and missed the "were" in the translations. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would literally translate Luke 1:2 thus:

> as delivered to us [by] those [who] from [the] beginning **having become**
> eyewitnesses and servants of the word,

The bolded text is the translation of the verb γενόμενοι.

Now, I can imagine the committee translation process in the NIV, NASB, NKJV, ESV, etc, that usually begin with the literal rendering the text as here.  The "English polishers" would immediately change this to something like:

> as delivered to us by those who were eyewitnesses and servants of the
> word

The second translation still contains all the information of the first translation without the very Hebraistic or classical style about it.  And it appears this is exactly what most versions have done.  That is, "having become" is "smoothed out" to be "were" or equivalent.

Comment: Good answer.  I stayed up too late when I looked at this verse and missed the "were" in the translations.  Thanks for responding to this question.